# Find the Particular Integral of the following ODE using the variation of parameters?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE is $$xy''-(1+x)y'+y=x^2$$ and the Complementary Function (homogenous solution) is $$y_{\small CF} =A y_1+By_2$$ where, $y_1=e^x$ and $y_2=x+1$.

However, while computing the particular integral by $$y_{\small p}=-y_1\int{\frac{y_2f(x)}{W(y_1,y_2)}}+y_2\int{\frac{y_1f(x)}{W(y_1,y_2)}}$$
(where $f(x)=x^2$)

the particular integral comes out to be $$y_{\small p} = -\frac{1}{2}(x^3+3x^2+6x+6)$$
and $$xy{\small p}''-(1+x)y{\small p}'+y{\small p}$$ comes out to be equal to $x^3$ instead of $x^2$.

Any help in this matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: What did you calculate the Wronskian to be?

Comment: The Wronskian was $-x e^x$

Comment: Not exactly. I intend to solve this ODE through 'Variation of Parameters'.

Comment: Also, more than simply finding the solution, I am more interested as to why this method yields an incorrect result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is not correct:
$$y_{\small p} = -\frac{1}{2}(x^3+3x^2+6x+6)$$
Because before to apply the method of variation of parameters; you need to put the differential equation on the canonical form:
$$y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=f(x)$$
Now the DE:
$$xy''-(1+x)y'+y=x^2$$
Becomes:
$$y''-\left(1+\dfrac 1x\right)y'+\dfrac yx=\color{red}{x}$$
So that the function $f$ is $f(x)=x$ and not $f(x)=x^2$. Apply the method now and you will find the correct answer:
$$y_p=-x^2$$
And the solution is:
$$y(x)=c_1e^x+c_2(x+1)-x^2$$